# what are the negative effects of index every column?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing

I understand indexing all column would be extremely costly on server space, but now days, space is cheap.

Assume space isn't an issue, is there any negative consequences from indexing every column in a table?

Comment: Indexes need to be updated on `insert` and `update` statements.

Comment: Sometimes they're even updated on `DELETE`s!

Comment: That's great HABO, the servers should really be proud of themselfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is memory cheap? Because when you load those indexes into memory, which is required in order to read from them, they take up memory.

Are CPU and I/O cheap? Because when you add an index on every single column, every single modification requires maintenance on every index. So if you have a table with 10 indexes, and modify one row, this could be 10 or more writes. This is costly all around.

Comment: I am now kind of expecting to get grilled by the stackflow community for asking this question...

Comment: Read: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/disk-space-is-cheap/ - that post is about data type choice, so it doesn't even get into the cost of maintaining indexes, but the thrust is the same: if you stop at just analyzing the cost of disk space, you're not doing yourself any favors.